# creating an age range for ages - R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have this dataframe:

```
> set.seed(100)
> df <- data.frame(Age = sample(18:70, 30, replace = TRUE),
                 Sex = sample(0:1, 30, replace =TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
   Age Sex
1   34   0
2   31   1
3   47   0
4   20   1
5   42   1
6   43   1
7   61   0
8   37   1
9   46   1
10  27   0
11  51   0
12  64   1
13  32   1
14  39   1
15  58   1
16  53   0
17  28   1
18  36   1
19  37   0
20  54   0
21  46   0
22  55   0
23  46   0
24  57   0
25  40   1
26  27   0
27  58   0
28  64   0
29  47   1
30  32   0
```

And I want to create another column with the age range for each age with this ranges:

```
> df_range <- data.frame(Age_Range = c("Lower than 26", "26 to 30", "31 to 35", "36 to 40", "41 to 45", "46 to 50", "51 to 55", "56 to 60", "61 to 65", "More than 65"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df_range
       Age_Range
1  Lower than 26
2       26 to 30
3       31 to 35
4       36 to 40
5       41 to 45
6       46 to 50
7       51 to 55
8       56 to 60
9       61 to 65
10  More than 65
```

I know I can do it by creating a huge table where the first column have all the possible ages (-1000 to 1000 to avoid outliers, for example) and its second column the range for each age, also I could do it with an `ifelse()` for each range. However, isn't there a more efficient way? Maybe something like a TRUE VLOOKUP in excel?

Comment: You may use `cut` to create the 'Range'

Comment: Or `findInterval` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/findInterval)

Comment: Can't find a suitable duplicate although I've seen one in the past.

Comment: With `findInterval` as stated above you can do something like: `df$Agegroup<-findInterval(df$Age,c(20,25,35,60))`. Then just relevel after converting to factor.

Answer (score 1):

to cut with uniform range, you can use
`df$age_range = cut_width(df$Age,width=5,boundary=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `findInterval` as stated by @RLave above(didn't `set.seed`): You should look at `left.open` and `right.open` and tweak them as required.

```
 df$Agegroup<-findInterval(df$Age,c(0,26,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,200))
    library(dplyr)
    df<-df %>% 
      rename(Age_range=Agegroup) %>% 
      mutate(Age_range=as.factor(Age_range))
    levels(df$Age_range)<-c("Lower than 26","26 to 30","31 to 35","36 to 40",
                            "41 to 45","46 to 50","51 to 55","56 to 60","61 to 65",
                            "More than 65")#Kinda tiring
```

Output(truncated):

```
   Age Sex     Age_range
1   29   1      26 to 30
2   52   0      51 to 55
3   38   1      36 to 40
4   56   0      56 to 60
5   33   1      31 to 35
6   20   1 Lower than 26
7   40   1      41 to 45
8   31   0      31 to 35
9   43   0      41 to 45
10  50   0      51 to 55
```